# Check Pattern or password is enabled on device in react native

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to detect device has pattern or password in react native? Actually I want to prompt the user that device has no password or pattern if device has no password or pattern

Comment: You might have to find a react-native module that does the same or write native code for it.

Comment: have any solution find..? i am also trying that thing